# how to include aem custom dam asset handler in a workflow

Tags: workflow, aem, assets, dam

i followed the custom dam handler blog and was able to achieve what was mentioned in that. My requirement is that i need to get **thumbnails created for Doc and Xls files** when any dam asset is uploaded. I have gone through the **DAM UPDATE ASSET workflow** and the steps in that just work fine for TXT, IMAGES and PDF files.

i have tried adding **application/vnd.ms-excel and  application/msword MIME** types but didnt work. May i know what i am missing and where i am missing ? in custom handler what code do i need to write to get thumbnails to be created ?

[image: dam handler error 1]

[image: dam handler error 2]

[image: dam handler error 3]

thanks,
Tarun Singh

Comment: Can you attache the relevant error log as text rather than an image? It will help people answer your question.

Comment: And by the way, do you get the same result if you upload a document without white-spaces in the filename?